# How to remove :focus, :active css when user unblocks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap3 button like this

[image: before click]

when user click the button it render model and when user closed the model
the button is not return to the old bg color.

[image: after click]

user must click the bg page or click anything in the page then the button bg color will return to the old one.

How to return the bg color to the first one after user close the model ?

CSS:

```
*:focus {
  outline:none !important;
}
```

to remove outline when use are clicked the button.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etfu9zev/

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean **modal**? Please provide enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: A link to a live version of your project / code would be helpful?

Comment: Please provide a Snippet or Fiddle of a sample of your code that illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: sorry, I add jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etfu9zev/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ever used bootstrap until now, the problem is obvious. Someone should have worked on it already, but coding is tough... Here is my solution:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Something</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
*:focus {
    outline:none !important;
}
body{
    background:#DDD;
}
.btn-success:focus{
    background-color: #5CB85C;
}
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/q9bnf5qy/) that illustrates it.

All you have to do is to make **.btn-something:focus** to have the same color as **.btn-something**. You can add the code for any type of button of bootstrap in your stylesheet, causing a reflow, but I'd rather cut the focus part from the bootstrap css.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Vann, this is solve my problem but, I need to over write `label Primary Success Info Warning Danger` right ? is there another way to solve this but not over write a lot of class ?

Comment: Unefortunately, no, because every class `Primary Success Info Danger Warning` has it's own distinctive colors on :hover and on :focus. Try to cut down the parts from bootstrap.css. +1 Answer please.